# How to filter city as per selected state in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have data in dropdown now I want to filter city as per selected state, how can I do this in reactJs?

**Giving Error:-**
[image]

**API Response:-**
[image]

**My code:-**

```js
function setSelectedOption(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
  let selectedState = e.target.value;
}

function GetEgyptStates() {
  const [egyptData, setEgyptData] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/states-and-districts.json")
      .then((response) => {
        setEgyptData(response.data);
        console.log(response.data)
      });
  }, []);

  if (!egyptData) return null;

  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={setSelectedOption}>
        <option> -- Select State -- </option>
        {Object.entries(egyptData.Egypt).map(([key, val]) => (
          <option>{key}</option>
        ))}
      </select>

      <select>
        <option> -- Select City -- </option>
        {egyptData.Egypt.selectedState.map((state) => (
          <option>{state}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

ThankYou for your efforts!

Comment: seems `egyptData.Egypt.selectedState` is undefined

Comment: how to fix it ?

Comment: `egyptData.Egypt.selectedState && egyptData.Egypt.selectedState.map()`

Comment: this is not filtering city when I change state.

Answer (score 2):

I think this code can help you
**If you want get property with string name you can use **setEgyptData[selectedState]**

```js
  function GetEgyptStates() {
    const [egyptData, setEgyptData] = React.useState();
    const [cities,setCities]=React.useState([]);
    const [selState,setselState]=React.useState([]);
    const [selcity,setselcity]=React.useState([]);
    function setSelectedOption(e) {
        console.log(e.target.value);
        let selectedState = e.target.value;
        setselState(selectedState)
        setCities(setEgyptData[selectedState])
      }
    React.useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData=async ()=>{ 
          let response =await axios
        .get("http://localhost:3000/states-and-districts.json");
          setEgyptData(response.data);
    }
    if(!egyptData)
        fetchData();
    }, [egyptData]);
  
    if (!egyptData) return null;
  
    return (
<div>
      <select value={selState} onChange={setSelectedOption}>
        <option> -- Select State -- </option>
        {Object.entries(egyptData.Egypt).map(([key, val]) => (
          <option key={key}>{key}</option>
        ))}
      </select>

      <select value={selcity} onChange={({target})=>setselcity(target.value)}>
        <option> -- Select City -- </option>
        {cities.map((city) => (
          <option key={city}>{city}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: After select state from dropdown, this is display hiding...

Comment: you must keep selected value in state 
**you must do the same for the city**

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: selectedState is not defined, now giving this error.

Comment: I change the sample, look age
`const [selState,setselState]=React.useState();`

Comment: I change answer totally please try again

Comment: 'value' is not defined  no-undef

giving this error

Comment: if it has still an error give some data that I test it

Answer (score 2):

Your `setSelectedOption` function does not set state to update the UI

For the fix,

You should introduce

```
const [selectedState, setSelectedState] = useState()
```

And add it to `setSelectedOption`

```
function setSelectedOption(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
  let selectedState = e.target.value;
  setSelectedState(selectedState)
}
```

By the way, `egyptData.Egypt.selectedState` does not exist in your current code too, you should use `egyptData.Egypt[selectedState]`

```
{egyptData.Egypt[selectedState].map((state) => (
   <option>{state}</option>
))}
```

Comment: this is not working...

Answer (score 1):

seems `egyptData.Egypt.selectedState` is undefine like @Bravo said

you can do it like `egyptData.Egypt.selectedState && egyptData.Egypt.selectedState.map()` or `egyptData?.Egypt?.selectedState?.map()`

it seems like it renders before data your set method call (useEffect)

instead of doing this  `if (!egyptData) return null` try `if (!egyptData) return <></>`

Comment: still not working actually city is not displaying after select state...

Answer (score 1):

if you create variable with `let` it will only access in that block in you're code `selectedState` only use in `setSelectedOption` function you have to create state to declare as a global variable

```js
function GetEgyptStates() {
  const [egyptData, setEgyptData] = React.useState(null);
  const [selectedState , setselectedState] = React.useState('');


function setSelectedOption(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
 setselectedState(e.target.value)
}


  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/states-and-districts.json")
      .then((response) => {
        setEgyptData(response.data);
        console.log(response.data)
      });
  }, []);

  if (!egyptData) return null;

  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={(e)=>setSelectedOption(e)}>
        <option> -- Select State -- </option>
        {Object.entries(egyptData.Egypt).map(([key, val]) => (
          <option>{key}</option>
        ))}
      </select>

      <select>
        <option> -- Select City -- </option>
        {egyptData?.Egypt[selectedState]?.map((state) => (
          <option>{state}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: this is not working...

Comment: sorry it's my mistake try this in your select city dropdown 
remove single quotes
`{egyptData.Egypt[selectedState].map((state) => (
          <option>{state}</option>
        ))}`

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: now giving this error

Comment: `egyptData?.Egypt[selectedState]?.map()` this will fix it

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine now...

**Code given below:-**

```js
function GetEgyptStates() {
  const [egyptData, setEgyptData] = React.useState(null);
  const [cities, setCities] = React.useState([]);
  const [state, selState] = React.useState();
  function setSelectedOption(e) {
    
    let state = e.target.value;
    setCities(egyptData.Egypt[state]);
  }
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      axios
        .get("http://localhost:3000/states-and-districts.json")
        .then((response) => {
          setEgyptData(response.data);
          console.log(response.data);
        });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  if (!egyptData) return null;

  return (
    <div>
      <select value={state} onChange={setSelectedOption}>
        <option> -- Select State -- </option>
        {Object.entries(egyptData.Egypt).map(([key, val]) => (
          <option>{key}</option>
        ))}
      </select>

      <select>
        <option> -- Select City -- </option>
        {cities.map((city) => (
          <option>{city}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thank you all of you for your support!